# watch a specific directory and push the new image path in Gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

Is there a way to watch a specific directory using Gstreamer and push the new image path to pipeline for For more information, see the picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGJwW.png